# How would you mock/sub a request for an Express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

If for example I wanted to mock a req.body within this given method, how would I do that?

```
app.get('/test', exposeDb, function(req, res) {
    req.dbService.getUserByID(req.body, function(err, result) {
        if (result == 5) {
            console.log(result);
            res.json({result: result});
        }
        else {
            console.log(result);
            res.json({result: result});
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my current test:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        var getUserByIDStubE = sinon.stub(dbService, 'getUserByID').callsFake(cb => {
            cb(undefined, 5);
        });


      });

    it('TESTSETSTETS', function(done) {        
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/test')
            .send({ req })
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.body.result.should.equal(5);
                done();
            });
    });
```

I want to mock a req.body so that it can be passed into the route call.

Thanks!

NOTE that I'm using chai-http, sinon for the stub.

Comment: What do you want `req.body` to contain?